# How can I change the startpoint at logx in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logging, statistics

Given the following code:

```
def plotyear(year):
    data = gapminder[gapminder.year == year]

    data.plot.scatter('gdp_per_day','life_expectancy', logx = True)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHtw6.png)

The scale starts from 10^-2 and goes up to 10^4. How can I change the range to 10^0 - 10^2 to make it more precise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)?

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot.xlim(1,100) helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can  set x limits of the current axes with [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

```
matplotlib.pyplot.xlim(1,100)
```